# flutter not running on real device

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am a beginner and i was try to run Flutter Demo code for the first time just after download it and it did not work i try to check out every thing and it seems fine .and here its some screens shoot, i hope any one can help me.[main.Dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogOjj.png),[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsSV8.png),[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpRxs.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoMqB.png),[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79J2F.png)

Answer (score 0):

please check can you build apk file?

[image]

You will get response from android studio or you can find debug and release version In the following path:

PROJECT PATH\build\app\outputs\apk

If building apk process finished successfully please check your phone storage capacity because I fixed same issue with this solution